# Are there artists in Canada, USA or Europe who also claim to have been punished for going against government, corporate, media or military objectives?

Tags: united-states, law, europe, canada, south-korea

South Korean artists file a class-action lawsuit against their government over blacklisting, as stated by CNN here: (http://www.cnn.com/2017/02/08/asia/south-korea-ex-culture-minister-indicted/) artists are suing because they were blacklisted for going against government in power.

Are there artists in Canada, USA or Europe who also claim to have been punished for going against government, corporate, media or military objectives?

Comment: What does blacklisting imply? Certainly I would say that in Western Europe there are no artists jailed or with a travel ban due to criticism to the government, but sometimes some people claim that their work not being included in publicly funded expositions due to political manouvers, or that a theater act in a public venue is cancelled due to political decisions.

Comment: @SJuan76 very good point and worthy of an answer by you IMO. In Canada the CRTC mandates 30% of radio and TV mus be Canadian content. The government provides funding to artists to make songs / films. They could withdraw funding for anti-war songs against bombing of Libya or Afghanistan for example. Or protests to Trade Agreements, etc. Or against LGBT marriage for example. The list could be endless but... has anyone complained officially or in press stories?

Comment: Define "Europe", please. EU? EU+Turkey+Russia?

Comment: @MartinSchröder Good point. Turkey has a lot of media suppression going on and is a member of NATO wanting to join EU. There actions are well known as are Russia's recent history and Ukraine's recent history.  I would define Europe as EU + UK in this case even though it's not geographically accurate.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: Erdogan does *not* want to join the EU.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I think that is something he's been saying lately only because they don't want him on the inside. Last year they pushed hard for visa-less travel. Since 1987 they've been askikng to join the EU: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accession_of_Turkey_to_the_European_Union

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: The new constitution he seeks is not compatible with the EU. And he wants to introduce the death penalty again, which is also incompatible with the EU.

Comment: @MartinSchröder Not to mention arresting 10's of thousands of followers of Gullan movement and firing hundreds of thousands of others and wiping out newspapers that don't tow the AKP party line. These are immediate reasons why he is unacceptable to EU... which in turn causes knee-jerk reaction from him "Well we don't want to join EU anyway" which is contrary to 30 years of history.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix you describe a hypothetical Canadian blacklisting as the government choosing not to fund certain artists - is that what happened in South Korea? Was the blacklisting there a matter of just not receiving public funds, or was it a more extensive blacklisting than that? A blacklisting that also took away perhaps their ability to find private work, or to be seen on social media, or other ways of interfering with their career? - edit, i've read the linked cnn article and it DOES look like it's a blacklist from receiving government funds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pablo Hasél](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pablo_Has%C3%A9l) and [Valtònyc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valt%C3%B2nyc) are two unrelated rappers who claim that they were prosecuted in Spain for going against the government, the monarchy or security forces, although the Spanish judiciary claims they were prosecuted for insulting the king, supporting terrorism or other crimes committed with their songs.

Interestingly, Valtònyc fled to Belgium and he couldn't be extradited because the Belgian judiciary found that he had not committed any crime that could be prosecuted under Belgian law, because his songs would be allowed by freedom of speech according to the Belgian constitution.

Answer (score 3):

In the US and Canada there is a constitutionally protected freedom of speech, so the government should not go against any artists for their work. I do not of any cases of government blacklisting any artists.

Europe though is big and has a lot of countries in it. Not all of them have such a broad freedom of speech. The most obvious example I can think of is Russia and the artist group [Pussy Riot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pussy_Riot). There have been multiple cases where Russia has used force to shut down their performances, and in some cases members have been arrested.

Another (lesser) example of censorship is Germany, which has an [Index of Harmful Materials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censorship_in_the_Federal_Republic_of_Germany#Index_of_Harmful_Materials) that restricts certain forms of speech ranging from pornography to swastikas.

Comment: Pussy Riot was arrested for church vandalism which was easy to prove because they filmed it. Germany has ban against insulting foreign leaders so cartoonist was charged for mocking Turkey's Erdogan.

Comment: *"Germany has ban against insulting foreign leaders so cartoonist was charged for mocking Turkey's Erdogan."* Are you referring to the [Böhmermann Affair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%B6hmermann_affair)? (which was about a TV comedian, not a cartoonist, though). The prosecution dropped the charges in that case. But the German law is far less lenient regarding Nazi propaganda.

Comment: Today German court just ruled to continue ban of comedian's poem: https://www.rt.com/news/377001-germany-erdogan-poem-ban/

Comment: It's also vaguely bugged me that Germans always seem to be anti-something. The actual target changes, but the attitude doesn't.

Comment: Given that the first amendment to the US constitution significant predates McCarthyism, I find the argument in the first paragraph unconvincing.

Comment: Back when Lyndon Johnson was US president, he had Eartha Kitt blacklisted for speaking out against US policies (wrt Vietnam if I recall correctly.)